# My system won't load the GUI, how do I fix it permanently?

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, gui

I hope someone will be able to help me with this issue that is driving me crazy. I have a **Dell XPS 7590** (2019 model) that I've recently upgraded to **Windows 11 Pro**. I updated it to Windows 11 about two months ago, when it still was in beta and I've never had any problem in dual booting it with Ubuntu 20.04.

Two days ago, after performing a clean install of Windows 11 Pro and reinstalling Ubuntu 20.04 in **dual boot**, Ubuntu stopped loading the GUI correctly. After choosing Ubuntu from the GRUB menu, a **blinking cursor** (an underscore) appears at the top left corner of the screen and nothing happens. I managed to load the GUI by following [this guide](https://serverascode.com/2021/07/03/blinking-cursor-linux.html), but I'm wondering if it's possible to make it permanent without having to follow those steps every time I restart Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance to everyone who will help me figure out a solution.

Comment: You do not say if you have rebooted and its back to the problem.

Comment: I have this problem on a fairly regular basis, and use ctrl-alt-f3 then ctrl-alt-f2 to geta hybrid mode or to an  my GUI run.  For me, setting my graphics controller to either hybrid or integrated mode solves this problem.  Using Nvidia as the graphics driver in my system necessitates the fix I mentioned to get the GUI running.

Answer (score 0):

Enable GUI to start on boot:

`sudo systemctl set-default graphical`

Start GUI manually from a command line:

`sudo systemctl start gdm3`

Comment: Tried to do that with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally managed to solve the problem by logging into the tty console and running this command:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

After a restart, everything started running normally.